# SQL insert query inside select or where clause

Tags: mysql

Maybe my question above may be could be stupid , but I just want to know if is it possible to have insert query inside select or where.

The reason that I want to know that is if someone hack website or any application database, can the hacker input data to hacked database without my knowledge ?

the following example of SQL injection I see in other sites

```
http://www.example.com/empsummary.php?id=1 AND 1=-1 union select 1,group_concat(name,0x3a,email,0x3a,phone,0x2a),3,4,5,6,7,8,9 from employee
```

I know what exactly that above query does, but can the hacker input (use insert query) on the database or on any table ?

Comment: Generally...if you are escaping the parameters correctly, it should be impossible to be injected at all, and you should aim for that. (otherwise, you'd want to ensure that your scripts have the minimum permissions to the database, so if this particular page only needs to select, then it should only have select permissions on the account it uses to connect to the db).

Comment: Thanks, I know that , but the question is can any query like insert,update or maybe create executed from the above link or exploit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can happen, if the database interface is configured to allow multiple statements in a query.

An `INSERT` can't run as part of a `SELECT` statement. But it's possible that the exploit of a vulnerability could finish a SELECT and then execute a separate insert.

Say you have a vulnerable statement like this:

```
 SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE fee = '$var'
```

Consider the SQL text when `$var` contains:

```
 1'; INSERT INTO emp (id) VALUES (999); --
```

The SQL text could be something like this:

```
 SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE fee = '1'; INSERT INTO emp (id) VALUES (999); --'
```

If multi-statement queries are enabled in the database interface library, it's conceivable that an `INSERT` statement could be executed.

See: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: Thanks, That's help me, and understand it , but how can I verify if database interface is allow to exploit these types vulnerability ?